# What would be the problems society would face during a fantasy end of days scenario?

Tags: society, magic, apocalypse

Context: all the myths of gods, demons, devils, angels and other creatures are true and have re-emerged for an all-out war between each other. Humans have been caught in the crossfire and our civilization crumbled. and the earth-shattering war has brought along with it magic back to the world.

What would be the immediate effects on society be if electricity and advanced tec stopped working in said scenario due to the magic re-working nature? only the basics of all we know now work. And we have yet to learn any form of manipulating said magic.

Comment: The answer to this question would fill a book. Such questions are usually closed as too broad.

Comment: This is too broad.  It's basically asking us to write the story for you.  You'll get better and more informative answers if we narrow the scope a lot.  (a) what's the nature of magic on your world?  (b) how far into the battle are we?  (c) How long since the power and gasoline ran out?  (d) Do the combatants care at all about humanity?  (e) Are combatants prone to fighting in city centers?  (f) Are there any areas where combat isn't happening? (g) Are there sanctuaries?  (h) Is it possible to petition those gods/demons for protection? (i) What is your expectation for the role of humanity? Etc.

Comment: (j) Are the combatants assailable by humans at all (what weapons of ours work?)  (k) Do the combatants require access to our food supplies?  (l) Do the combatants number in the 100's, 1,000's, 1,000,000's?  My point here is this: if humans don't matter, it doesn't matter how they react.  If they matter, then there must be a path to salvation.

Comment: If *"electricity [...] stopped working"* then everybody is dead and Earth is a ball of atomic nuclei and whetever particles you call chargeless electrons, rapidly collapsing into a strange state of matter. Rocks, trees, humans and the very molecules and atoms are held together by electrical forces. This is a very short story.

Answer (score 2):

Total collapse.

Now that's bound to get this answer on the low quality review list. Just re-read the question before you do so, and think about it for a little bit.

All the power's out. No news. All communications are out. Full scale Armageddon. Battles with gods, demons, angels and the whole supernatural menagerie. No society on the planet can function.

The armed forces around the world might rally. That's the advantage of military discipline and organization. If their weapons can harm or kill supernatural beings then they might gain a small amount of ground.

Magic is back. But is there enough time to learn anything useful? Probably not. Also it depends on what sort of magic is available. Besides learning magic suggests you need to be taught by someone who already knows it. Even if they exist, they will be busy trying to survive.

No. It's instant total social collapse globally with the supernatural equivalent of thermonuclear war raging 24/7. That's it. Society everywhere just collapses. Time for the extinction of the human species.

Comment: Without the OP providing any context for his question, this is the only supportable answer.

Answer (score 0):

**The Moment After**

Everyone would be in shock as all electronics stop. Computer users will try power on their computers. Phone users will try and restart with devices before frustratingly hitting it a couple times before sitting in a corner as they can no longer post food posts onto Instagram. Cars would veer to a stop and general chaos as the traffic lights all turn off, indicators stop working and their GPS turns off leading them to drive into the harbor. Planes engines stop and mass panic occurs as the several hundred flights left in the air all scramble to talk to the control tower before realizing they now have a very limited time to land their planes and that every other plane is in the same situation.

The lucky few people with emergency shelters enter their shelter. Before realizing that their back up generators and air pumps have stopped functioning. The president of the United states is escorted to a secure room before he realizes he can no longer tweet about it. In anger he presses his big red shiny button but nothing happens since all electricity is gone.

**A Couple Minutes Later**

People look up and nervously ask a passing stranger, "What happened". As the conclusion that all electricity is gone, those who witness the battling of Gods, Angels and Demons flee indoors. The unfortunate people who are near other creatures suffer a horrible fate, unable to post about their literal death online before dying. People start to figure out what happened and band together into groups. They raid stores, warehouses, board up their houses like it was the zombie apocalypse.

**Cue Walking Dead but with fantasy creatures instead of zombies and instead of a cure, they learn magic**

Comment: A reasonable scenario, but they learn magic how? The question specifies humans haven't learned magic yet. While now might be a good time. During Armageddon might be too late.

Comment: I would assume that some people, especially in tense situations would be able to manifest and harness magic. It will probably occur sporadically until they are able to associate the correct feeling with casting magic. Once a person learns, the people near them will also want to learn from them. People who are smart enough will then attempt to categorize it, but they would have to be in a well off group/secure location otherwise they would have more imminent concerns like living, food, water and safety.

Comment: I can see the attraction in making that assumption. However, I took my cue from the statement about learning magic and decided magic is based on learned skills. The trouble with learned skills is it takes time and practice to acquire them. This magic acquisition scenario might be akin to suddenly & unexpectedly gaining knowledge of nuclear physics during a thermonuclear war. While I don't underestimate how smart people are, the OP's apocalyptic scenario might be too overwhelming.

Comment: But OP's scenario mentions humans haven't learned magic yet. If it was recorded information, then the humans wouldn't have access to it, but it wouldn't be available to use, hence the accidental manifestation assumption.

Comment: I understand how & why you made your assumption. It's quite plausible. if I was writing a story like this I'd probably use it too. Well, only if I didn't think of something I thought was better. I made a different assumption about how things might work in the OP's world. In fact, yours might be a safer version of it to be in. But assumptions are precisely that, assumptions. Neither right nor wrong, unless evidence proves otherwise, merely ways to reason through a proposition.